# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS shows weird characters on boot (Live USB)

Tags: boot, 20.04, live-usb

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x10O1.jpg]

That is an image I took on my phone of the boot screen I'm getting. This happens when I select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu that shows up after booting from my live USB. Display safe mode works fine though. Any ideas?

Comment: Which tool did you use to make the drive, Rufus, SDC, UNetbootin, dd?

Comment: Hi, I used Rufus with the settings recommended on the Ubuntu help site (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: When you get to the grub menu when booting, press "e", Type a space and "nomodeset" on the linux line after --.. See if that boots it.